# Persistent Login with Passport.js no longer working. isAuthenticated returns false

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, session-cookies

I had this code working at some point and must have lost it in a careless save at some point. I am trying to achieve persistent login with passport but it does not seem to be doing that as I am getting `false` on the `isAuthentiacted` middleware.

Here is my primary server.js setup, as you can see the order is good. But I am not sure about the cookie settings as I'm new to this whole thing.

```
app.use(cookieParser('S3CRE7'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({ key: 'express.sid', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, maxAge: 3000}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('/users/', usersRouter);
app.use('/transcriptions', transRouter);
app.use(express.static('public'));

const basicStrategy = new BasicStrategy(function(username, password,     callback) {
  let user;
  User
    .findOne({username: username})
    .exec()
    .then(_user => {
      user = _user;
      if (!user) {
        return callback(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username'});
      }
      return user.validatePassword(password);
    })
    .then(isValid => {
      if (!isValid) {
        return callback(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password'});
      }
      else {
        return callback(null, user)
      }
    });
});

passport.use(basicStrategy);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Here is my initial Log In endpoint with custom callback function, which logs in just fine, as well as stores a cookie on the client side

```
router.post('/login',  function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('basic', function (err, account) {
    req.logIn(account, function() {
        res.status(err ? 500 : 200).send(err ? err : account);
    });
})(req, res, next)
});
```

isAuthenticated function:

```
const isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
    console.log('not authenticated');
}
```

First lines of where the authentication fails:

```
router.get('/', isAuthenticated, 
    (req, res) => {
                console.log(req);
});
```

Comment: That's a known issue reported at passport [issue#306](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/306) and also there is a workaround for it.